# android aapt dump resources no output

Tags: android, linux, terminal, binary, aapt

When I try to dump an apk resources using the AAPT on Android Jellybean and pre-Jellybean versions, it works fine. It displays the expected output.

```
aapt dump --values resources /system/framework/framework-res.apk
```

But when I try to run this command on KitKat and newer versions, it outputs literally nothing. I'm not really sure if ART runtime has something to do with this though.

Anyone knows what could be the cause of this? and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is in the android platform, when AAPT is ran on other OS, it works fine but when ran on inside android, it displays nothing.

Answer (score 4):

In android studio ,In between minimum SDK version and maximum SDK version keep as per your mobile android version.then clean project and try to run.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I've done on a Marshmallow Nexus 6 (6.0/MRA58K):

```
adb pull /system/framework/framework-res.apk
aapt dump --values resources framework-res.apk
```

it produced a 19 MiB long list of resource identifiers. The same commands on a Jelly Bean Nexus S (4.1.2/JZO54K) produced equivalent output, except it was half the size.

Comment: and please be sure that you are using the aapt inside android itself and not on PC.... aapt works fine on pc, the only problem is that it now stops working when ran inside android itself.